# Convert System.Drawing.Color to an int?

Tags: c#, .net

In the database, we have colors being stored as int's. (Don't ask... it's a really old app.)  Example:

-16777216 = black

I am able to convert -16777216 to #000000 (which I can actually use in the UI):

```
string htmlColor = ConvertToColor("-16777216");
```

Will return `"#000000"` from this method:

```
private string ConvertColor(string value)
{
    int valInt = Convert.ToInt32(value);
    System.Drawing.Color color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(valInt);
    return System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(color);
}
```

But now, to re-save the value in the same format, I'm having trouble going backwards:

```
string intColor = RevertColor("#000000");
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
private string RevertColor(string value)
{
    System.Drawing.Color color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(value);
    return ????;
}
```

Comment: That single int is propably just a combination of the 3 color values numerical values: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model#Numeric_representations That or some really wide collor channels. Thatr you are even trying to parse a negative number indicates that you are missreading those values on a binary level.

Comment: Does this method work:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.toargb?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Yeah, your -16777216  is equal to 0xFFFFFFFFFF000000 (long) or 0xFF000000 (int). It should be reasonably simple to reverse engineer things by using a simple decimal to hex calculator

Comment: By the way you're losing the alpha channel this way. Is there ever anything other than FF as the top byte?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `FromArgb()` worked going one direction, it seems like [`ToArgb()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.toargb?view=netframework-4.7.2) should work in the other direction:

```
private string RevertColor(string value)
{    
    return System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(value).ToArgb().ToString();
}
```

... but I'm also not sure I appreciate all the nuances in involved. If this doesn't do the job, please explain how it fails.

It also seems very weird that you want a string at all, if they're really `int` values in the database. That scares me you might be using **really unsafe** practices with how you save these values in the SQL. If nothing else, it's sub-optimal for performance to convert back and forth between strings like that. Thanks to culture/internationalization issues, those conversion operations are a lot more expensive than you might think.

Comment: As to your last comment, you are dead right. I just took over doing development on this 12+ year app, and there is plenty I don't like.  In this case, there is a table that stores a whole buncha user defined options, and it stores them all as strings, along with an other enum column to indicate what type the value should be converted to when it gets into the app.